# Is Linq Faster, Slower or the same?

Tags: c#, linq, performance

Is this:

```
Box boxToFind = AllBoxes.FirstOrDefault(box => box.BoxNumber == boxToMatchTo.BagNumber);
```

Faster or slower than this:

```
Box boxToFind ;
foreach (Box box in AllBoxes)
{
    if (box.BoxNumber == boxToMatchTo.BoxNumber)
    {
        boxToFind = box;
    }
}
```

Both give me the result I am looking for (`boxToFind`).  This is going to run on a mobile device that I need to be performance conscientious of.

Comment: Your first method won't compile.  Where returns an IEnumerable.  In order to be equivalent to the last one, you would hve to do AllBoxes.Last(box => ...)

Comment: Good point.  I changed my first method.  (Though I did not use last, because it "should" have only unique values)

Comment: You second method will compile, but will give you the last box that matches. Put a break; when you exit the if.

Comment: After your edit, the two are not actually doing the same thing. You should break out of the foreach loop once you find the first matching box. Otherwise, you either get a different result or if the box is unique you itterated the rest of the items for no reason therefore reducing performance.

Comment: As Chris Taylor put it, your own implementation is "last or default", not "first or default".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be about the same, except that you need to call `First` (or, to match your code, `Last`), not `Where`.
Calling `Where` will give you a set of matching items (an `IEnumerable<Box>`); you only want one matching item.

In general, when using LINQ, you need to be aware of deferred execution.  In your particular case, it's irrelevant, since you're getting a single item.

Comment: FirstOrDefault to avoid exceptions

Comment: @hunter: Unless he wants an exception.

Comment: @SLaks Or knows that a suitable element always exists.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is not important unless you've identified that this particular loop as a performance bottleneck through profiling.

If profiling does find it to be a problem, then you'll want to look into alternate storage.  Store the data in a dictionary which provides faster lookup than looping through an array.

Comment: A dictionary provides faster lookup than an array? It sure as hell does not. Dictionaries are backed by arrays, with additional calculations each time you access an element. Therefore, it's impossible for a dictionary to be faster than an array in an iteration.

Comment: @Rubys - Dictionary lookups are O(1), iterating through an array is O(n) so Dictionary lookups are faster for a large enough collection (assuming a sensible hash function).

Comment: @Rubys, Dictionary's are backed by an array of arrays.  A hashcode is used to identify exactly which element in the first array to retrieve.  There is no loop, just a simple mathematical calculation.  That gives you the second array, often referred to as the bucket.  Then the code loops through the bucket to find the exact item.  A good collection size and hash code will result in buckets that have only a few items.  The end result is that the dictionary is significantly faster than an array loop.

Comment: @Rubys: I think you're a little mixed up. Accessing an item at a known index in an array is as fast as it gets, yes. *Enumerating* over an array to *find* that index is *not* fast. A dictionary works by exploiting a hash function to attempt to bypass the slow part (enumerating) and jump straight to the fast part (access by index).

Comment: Two options: I misunderstood, or you misunderstood. You are three, so I"m inclined to think it's the former. How is enumerating over an entire dictionary faster than enumerating over an entire array? Lookups are faster on dictionary if you don't know the location of the item, but he may have simplified the example quite a bit, and in the actual method you have to preform some sort of calculation, or it could be anything. The form it's in right now, sure, dictionary, but It's not always possible

Comment: @Rubys, Dan Tao is saying something different.  He's comparing simple lookup in an array vs loopkup in a dictionary.  Yes, in that case an array is faster.  The original post is talking about looping through an array to find an item vs lookup in a dictionary.  In this case the dictionary is significantly faster unless the array is tiny or the hash code function sucks.

Comment: @Dan Tao, you're comparing array lookup vs dictionary lookup.  We're talking about looping through an array to find an item vs dictionary lookup.

Comment: @Sam: I interpreted your answer to suggest, basically, considering the use of a dictionary with keys corresponding to the value being looked up (in the OP's case, `BagNumber`). I am indeed comparing looping through an array with dictionary lookup. It seemed to me Rubys interpreted your answer to be suggesting looping over a dictionary. I feel we are in agreement, except that perhaps I did not express myself clearly enough. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Dan Tao. I think we're in agreement.  Direct lookup is faster in an array than a dictionary, but direct lookup in a dictionary is faster than looping over an array.  As always, specific results can vary depending on exact data (size of array vs quality of hash code).

Answer (score 3):

If micro-optimization is your thing, LINQ performs worse, [this is just one article](http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test), there are a lot of other posts you can find.

Comment: **Pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil.**  This is highly unlikely to be relevant to him.

Comment: Don't know if you read the comments for that article, but the bulk of the problem wasn't the iteration but the implicit cast in his original code.  Anders Hejlsberg pointed out that a query that didn't involve per-iteration cast operations was reasonably close to the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Micro optimization will kill you.
First, finish the whole class, then, if you have performance problems, run a profiler and check for the hotspots of the application.
Make sure you're using the best algorithms you can, **then** turn to micro optimizations like this.

In case you already did :
Slow -> Fast
LINQ < foreach < for < unsafe for (The last option is not recommended).
Abstractions will make your code slower, 95% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest is when you are using for loop. But the difference is so small that you are ignore it. It will only matter if you are building a real-time application but then for those applications maybe C# is not the best choice anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If AllBoxes is an IQueryable, it can be faster than the loop, because the queryable could have an optimized implementation of the Where-operation (for example an indexed access).

Comment: @Sam: IQueryable inherits IEnumerable, so a foreach loop works

Answer (score 0):

**LINQ is absolutely 100% slower**

Depends on what you are trying to accomplish in your program, but for the most part this is most certainly what I would call LAZY PROGRAMMER CODE...

You are going to essentially "stall-out" if you are performing any complex  queries, joins etc... total p.o.s for those types of functions/methods- just don't use it. If you do this the hard/long way you will be much happier in the long run...and performance will be a world apart.

**NOTE**:

I would definitely not recommend LINQ for any program built for    speed/synchronization tasks/computation 
(i.e. HFT trading &/or AT trading i-0-i for    starters).

**TESTED**:

It took nearly 10 seconds to complete a join in "LINQ" vs. < 1 millisecond.

Answer (score -2):

LINQ vs Loop – A performance test

```
LINQ: 00:00:04.1052060, avg. 00:00:00.0041052
Loop: 00:00:00.0790965, avg. 00:00:00.0000790
```

References:

http://ox.no/posts/linq-vs-loop-a-performance-test

http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html

Comment: This question asks about a specific query, your answer is about a completely different one.